# Enhance the "Flag summary"-UI in light of recent changes to flags

Tags: feature-request, flags

[With the now productive change to flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/310230) you no longer have to fear getting your flags declined due to the flagged Q/A being changed after you've flagged it, invalidating your flags. You can simply retract it.

This feature is great, <strike>as it prevents a lot of frustration</strike> as it saves diamond time, but it still has at least one problem that I'm aware of: Highly active flaggers. Quite a few people have a lot of flags available to them ([capped at 100](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)), and they tend to use most of them, which can be problematic to monitor. Personally, I'd rather not keep 68 (as of now) tabs open (and check them regularly), just to be able to retract my flag if necessary.

A possible way of approaching this problem would be to enhance the "Flag summary"-UI. If possible it'd be great to have another "tag" (similar to "Pending") added to Q/A's that have been editted since they were flagged.

[image: Custom tag]

Comment: One could probably make a UserScript for that purpose... _wink wink call the Gothdo_

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the reason for allowing flag retraction was to compensate for mis-clicks. Why in the world would you need to have 68 tabs open and check them regularly? If the flag becomes invalid by later actions, then *problem solved*. It does not need to be manually retracted.

Comment: @CodyGray Use-case for <3k users: Flag a question as off-topic for lacking an MCVE, but is then edited into scope by OP. How to keep track of that?

Comment: @CodyGray [Take a look at this, please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197208/310230). You may or may not care about your "Declined flags"-count, but I do.

Comment: @CodyGray The retraction of flag was done mainly because of the declination of flags after editing making the flag invalid IMO. It has happened to me also; I flag a post which was originally NAA, then it gets edited to make an answer, so the declination of flag is not the main problem, but it wastes moderator's time.

Comment: So whatever happened to the feature where edits to a flagged post would automatically invalidate the flag? I just don't see how this is a real problem, and if it is, your solution is solving the wrong problem. I don't want to have to monitor my "flag summary" any more than I want to have to keep 68 tabs open. The flag system just needs to be improved, not transfer the additional effort expenditure required from moderators onto users. I looked at the crap *once* already, I'm not making a commitment to keep monitoring it until it improves.

Comment: @CodyGray That'd be pretty easy, eh? Pretty abusable, too, sadly. One could just edit a space in & out of his post to dodge all the incoming flags. Doesn't make that much sense to me. Also, this is meant to be a first step, not the holy grail of flags. I just want some way of knowing what flags may have been invalidated without having to go through every single pending one.

Comment: "I just don't see how this is a real problem, and if it is, your solution is solving the wrong problem" - I agree so much with Cody here. By flagging a post, you're not committing to following the post through to completion. You noticed a problem, you flagged it, you move on. If you're really reviewing every single one of your flags to make sure no posts have been edited... I'm fairly sure there are better things for you to be doing with your time. Remember, declined flags aren't the worst thing in the world.

Comment: Guys...? [It's a workflow.](https://xkcd.com/1172/) But seriously, flagging a lot of things carries the risk of a few getting declined. There's not really anything you can do about it.

Comment: I'd love to have that 'edited' badge in the flag queue, too.